# <require> inside a globalResource component called with enhance in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

So, I'm trying to setup Aurelia in my Angular 1 web application so I can slowly upgrade. I need to do that since the application is too big and migrating everything at once would be impossible.

So, in my Aurelia folder I created a component folder with two components (`aurelia-component.js` and `another-component.js` with their views `aurelia-component.html` and `another-component.html`), I won't put the javascript as they are just two classes with one property, the html for both is the same, the only thing that changes is the text property value so I can differentiate them:

```
<template>
    <div>${text}</div>
</template>
```

My entry point `main.js` looks like this:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .basicConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .globalResources('components/aurelia-component')
        .globalResources('components/another-component');

        //window.aurelia = aurelia;
     aurelia.start()
        .then(a => { 
            window.aurelia = a;
        });
}
```

As you can see, this puts Aurelia in the window object so I can access it from my Angular app, I'll improve this later.
In my angular app I have this directive:

```
'use strict';

function AureliaContainer() {
    function Link($scope, element, attrs) {
        window.aurelia.enhance(element[0]);
    }
    //
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: Link
    };
}

module.exports = AureliaContainer;
```

I set this up in my app root with:

```
app.directive('aureliaContainer', require('./directives/aurelia.container'));
```

And in my Angular View I have these divs with my directive that calls the `enhance` function from Aurelia:

```
<div aurelia-container>
    <aurelia-component></aurelia-component>
</div>
<div aurelia-container>
    <another-component></another-component>
</div>
```

The reason I have two `aurelia-container` in the html is that I know I'll have to have more than one when I'm migrating the application.
And this works fine, both components load normally in the screen.
The problem is when I try to call another component from within one of those components.
What I did was, I created a new component called `test-component.js` with its view `test-component.html`. The html for this is just:

```
<template>
    <h1>Header</h1>
</template>
```

And then, from the `aurelia-component.html` I called it using:

```
<template>
    <require from="./test-component"></require>
    <div>${text}</div>
    <test-component></test-component>
</template>
```

Now, when I load the page, the `test-component` actually loads but the `<div>${text}</div` part of `aurelia-component` doesn't and I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'behaviorInstructions' of undefined
```

I really don't understand why this error is happening, I should be able to load a custom element from within another one normally, shouldn't I. Or is there a limitation when you use `enhance`?

I also tried to use `setRoot` in both divs with no success, just one of them is loaded.

Maybe there's a better approach for this?
Again, I can't migrate my entire application at once, it's just no feasible.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I know nothing about progressive enhancement in Aurelia. And cannot comment about its suitability for your scenario.

But I am wondering if maybe you missed some Au dependencies (like binding or templating?)

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/app-configuration-and-startup/8

```
aurelia.use
    .defaultBindingLanguage()
    .defaultResources()
    .developmentLogging()
    .globalResources('resources/my-component');
```

That might explain why it fails when you want it to render a template?

Comment: I'll try to do that, but the funny thing is that, when I remove the `<test-component> ` the part that didn't load starts loading again.